# how to assign back categorical variables to train and test data after training and testing using inverse_transform?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-engineering

how to assign back categorical variables to train and test data after training and testing using inverse_transform? Like training and testing, data will have encoded numerical values. So, how to assign back categorical values to those variables to train and test dataset after training and testing?
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ordinal data

Use this to encode

```
  
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
oe=OrdinalEncoder()
social['Gender']=oe.fit_transform(social[['Gender']])
```

Use this to decode

```
social['Gender']=oe.inverse_transform(social[['Gender']])
```

If you are using nominal variables

Use this to encode

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
  
ohe = OneHotEncoder()

temp_var= ohe.fit_transform(social[['Gender']])
```

Use this to decode

```
temp_var2=ohe.inverse_transform(temp_var)
```

Hope it helps